# No console output from Xcode 11 / iOS 13

Tags: xcode, ios13, xcode11

My console is providing no output, no `print`s or system debug info on the right side and no variables on the left. I have both console windows open and I do have "All Output" selected. I have tried restarting Xcode and the machine itself but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. For the sake of debugging I am using Swift, I am unsure if this is related but it happened after enabling multiple windows but this may be a coincidence.

The issue is specific to each simulator as the only fix I have found is creating a new simulator but even this breaks after the first build and run.

Looking around I have seen this issue occur for others on Xcode 8 and adding the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` argument to the run scheme fixes it for those, I have tried and this does not work in this case. I suspect that this is Xcode 11 / iOS 13 specific as did not happen once on prior versions in my experience.

Are there any longterm fixes for this?

Comment: it seems like sometimes Xcode doesn't replace the previous build of your app with your latest build, so whatever you added afterward, the existing build doesn't reflect the newly added code like prints and new functions.  I had to manually remove the app from the device.

Comment: For me this happens a lot when using multiple windows (the new feature on iPadOS 13, based on `UIWindowSceneDelegate`). Closing all but 1 window resolves the issue on the next run.

Comment: @Klaas this works for me too. Thank you!

Comment: Agree. Close all other windows. Run again. Then add another window for further development. Repeat above.

Comment: Closing windows worked for me, too. I have a simple app to test UIScene's, running on iOS 13.5 and iPadOS 13.5. On the iPhone there is only ever 1 scene, and the debug console always displays output as it should. On iPad I had 8 scenes, and the debug console wouldn't show any "print" output. I closed all windows except for one (by dragging up in the App Switcher), then on the next launch the console worked again. I could then "Show All Windows" for the app and click "Reopen Closed Windows" and then the console continued to work (even after kill/starting the app).

Answer (score 3):

For XCode 11 users, not getting any output in their console, assuming that you have the console active (view > debug area > activate console), you'll have to right-click the `live preview` and select `debug preview`, as follows:

[image]

After that, you'll start getting output in your console!

[image]

The output above is the following source code, that you can create as a view let's say TestView.swift and copy/paste:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print("Hello world!") }) {
            Text("Click me!")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```